# Знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы при выводе данных из БД

Tags: python, кодировка

Есть запрос к базе данных.

```
def get_valid_pumps_query():
    session = Session()
    pumps = session.query(Pump).filter(
        Pump.max_stage_count > 0
    )
    return pumps
```

есть функция для выбора топ списка

```
def get_pumps_toplist(target, casing, selection_opts: SelectionOpts):
    valid_pumps = get_valid_pumps_query()
    # подгружаем и фильтруем насосы так, чтобы влезли в трубу с заданным зазором
    ...
    pumps_with_criteria.sort(key=lambda pwc: pwc[:3])
    # возвращаем насосы, упорядоченные по метрике
    return [pump_with_criteria[-1] for pump_with_criteria in pumps_with_criteria]
```

У меня возникла проблема при выводе данных

```
eps_list = app.get_pumps_toplist(attrs, well_state)
    for eps in eps_list:
        print(eps.motor.model)
```

Результат получается таким:

> 70-STD KM-200-86
>   ???20-117?5

Вместо кириллицы появляются знаки вопроса.
Кто знает почему так? Как решить проблему?

Очень странно, что у знакомого этой проблемы не наблюдается. Т.е. он с помощью git перешел, на мою ветку запустил код, и у него все нормально.

Comment: выводится в консоль pycharm.

Comment: при использовании `print(repr(s))` все равно выводит со знаком вопроса `'????6?-117/?1'` `print(ascii(s))` тоже не помогло.

Comment: а почему тогда у знакомого этот код выдает и кириллицу тоже? проблема наблюдается только у меня

Comment: сделал правку вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**проблема решена!!!** 
перед стартом приложения необходимо выполнить следующее:

```
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "AMERICAN.AL32UTF8"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bdOut.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Comment: а что такое bdOut?

Comment: это - s - строка, выгружаемая из БД.

Comment: не помогло. выводит все равно со знаком вопроса 
b'????6?-117/?1'